# C# Entity Framework and couch DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, couchdb

I am aware that C# Entity Framework will allow us to work with MySQL. But is it possible to connect any other like Couch DB in the place of MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

CouchDb is a document-oriented NoSQL database.

Entity Framework (EF) is an **object-relational mapper** to work with relational data using domain-specific objects. It is meant to be used with Relational databases.

As CouchDb uses HTTP as its transport protocol and it is REST based, you could easily interact with it using any HTTP enabled client. Try using MyCouch which is a simple async, open sourced, CoucDb client written in C#. It builds on top of the async HttpClient and lets you work with native JSON and/or entities/POCOs.

Check this out: [Get up and running with CouchDb and C# using MyCouch on Windows](http://danielwertheim.se/get-up-and-running-with-couchdb-and-c-using-mycouch-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it might be helpful for others.

While EF Core doesn't support CouchDB, in the last few years I worked on a library to have a similar experience.

https://dev.to/matteobortolazzo/couchdb-and-c-efcore-like-queries-2ma4

https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/couchdb-net

```cs
var skywalkers = await context.Rebels
        .Where(r => 
            r.Surname == "Skywalker" && 
            (
                r.Battles.All(b => b.Planet == "Naboo") ||
                r.Battles.Any(b => b.Planet == "Death Star")
            )
        )
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.Name)
        .ThenByDescending(r => r.Age)
        .Take(2)
        .Select(
            r => r.Name,
            r => r.Age
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```